# Change drag&drop cursor on macOS with JavaFX

Tags: java, macos, javafx, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

How can i change the cursor on macOS with JavaFX when i drag an item?

I have tried to use the function `pane.setCursor()` that change the cursor, but when I drag an item I see a white paper behind the cursor.

```java
//drag detection for node dragging
pane.setOnDragDetected ( event -> {
    ImageCursor cursor = 
        new ImageCursor(new Image("/cursor.png"));

    pane.setCursor(cursor); 
});
```

Example:

1. Before drag purple line
2. Drag line
3. After drag

Drag and drop with custom cursor:

[image: drag and drop with custom cursor]

I have tried to run the code on Ubuntu 19 and Windows 10, but this problem isn't there.

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using?  I tried with JavaFX 12.0.2 on macOS 10.14.6 and I didn't get the "page" image behind the cursor I set.